# Python - Printing from a list that contains values from a class

Tags: python

I'm trying to print out the values of the variable called Deck that is a list of values that use a class:

```py
class Card:
      def __init__(self,suit,value):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value

Suits = ['Hearts','Spades','Clubs','Diamonds']
Values = ['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K','A']

Deck = [Card(suit,value) for suit in Suits for value in Values]
```

But whenever i try to print:

```py
Deck = [Card(suit,value) for suit in Suits for value in Values]
print(Deck)
```

It gives me:

```
<__main__.Card object at 0x054C7B10>
```

Comment: That's the default string representation of an object.  To override that functionality, define your own [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) method of `Card` objects.

Answer (score 1):

The printed version of your class can be overridden in a custom `__repr__` method:

```
class Card:

  def __init__(self,suit,value):
    self.suit = suit
    self.value = value

  def __repr__(self):
    return ' of '.join([self.value, self.suit])     


Suits = ['Hearts','Spades','Clubs','Diamonds']
Values = ['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K','A']

Deck = [Card(suit,value) for suit in Suits for value in Values]

print(Deck)
```

Result:

`[2 of Hearts, 3 of Hearts, 4 of Hearts, 5 of Hearts, 6 of Hearts, 7 of Hearts, 8 of Hearts, 9 of Hearts, 10 of Hearts, J of Hearts, Q of Hearts, K of Hearts, A of Hearts, 2 of Spades, 3 of Spades, 4 of Spades, 5 of Spades, 6 of Spades, 7 of Spades, 8 of Spades, 9 of Spades, 10 of Spades, J of Spades, Q of Spades, K of Spades, A of Spades, 2 of Clubs, 3 of Clubs, 4 of Clubs, 5 of Clubs, 6 of Clubs, 7 of Clubs, 8 of Clubs, 9 of Clubs, 10 of Clubs, J of Clubs, Q of Clubs, K of Clubs, A of Clubs, 2 of Diamonds, 3 of Diamonds, 4 of Diamonds, 5 of Diamonds, 6 of Diamonds, 7 of Diamonds, 8 of Diamonds, 9 of Diamonds, 10 of Diamonds, J of Diamonds, Q of Diamonds, K of Diamonds, A of Diamonds]`

Answer (score 1):

When the `print` function is asked to print an object, that output is text. So, if the object is not itself text, `print` needs some text representation of that object.

You can either do that explicitly – for example, by some explicit function call to get a text string – or implicitly, with the magic methods for text representation.

An example of the explicit option:

```python
for item in collection:
    text = "The {0.denominator} of {0.suit}".format(item)
    print("{0}\n".format(text))
```

See the [Python documentation for text formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

An example of defining string-representation methods for a class:

```python
class Card:

    ...

    def __str__(self):
        text = "The {0.denominator} of {0.suit}".format(self)
        return text

    def __repr__(self):
        text = "<Card: {0.denominator} of {0.suit}>".format(self)
        return text

for item in collection:
    print(item)
```

See the Python documentation for the magic [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) and [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) text-representation methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `namedtuple`, which has a repr for humans:

```
import collections as ct


suits = "♠ ♣ ♥ ♦".split()
ranks = "2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K A".split()

Card = ct.namedtuple("Card", "suit rank")
deck = [Card(suit, rank) for suit in suits for rank in ranks]

print(deck)
# [Card(suit='♠', rank='2'), Card(suit='♠', rank='3'), , ...]
```